# Writing out to a file in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

The goal of this is to check if the character taken into account is a number or operand and then output it into a list which will be written out to a txt file. 
I'm wondering which process would be more efficient, whether to do it as I stated above (writing it to a list and then writing that list out into a file) or being writing out into a txt file right from the procedure. 
I'm new with scheme so I apologize if I am not using the correct terminology

```
(define input '("3" "+" "4"))

(define check
   (if (number? (car input))
    (write this out to a list or directly to a file)
    (check the rest of file)))
```

Another question I had in mind, how can I make it so that the check process is recursive? 
I know it's a lot of asking but I've getting a little frustrated with checking out the methods that I have found on other sites. 
I really appreciate the help!

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html?q=output%20to%20file

Comment: What is the entire program supposed to do? I don't quite understand it. Is it supposed to output 7?

Comment: No, it's not evaluating anything. It is simply looking at the characters within the string and writing out into a file whether the character is a number or an operand.
so output for "3 + 4" should be "number," "operand," "number."
My question is how to write this into a txt file in the definition for "check"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to split the functionality in two separate procedures, one for generating a list of strings and the other for writing them to a file. For the first procedure, I'll give you the general idea so you can fill-in the blanks (this is a homework after all), it follows the standard structure of a recursive solution:

```
(define (check input)
  (cond ((null? input) ; the input list is empty
         <???>)        ; return the empty list
        ((string->number (car input)) ; can we convert the string to a number?
         (cons "number"  <???>)) ; add "number" to list, advance the recursion
        (else                    ; the string was not a number
         (cons "operand" <???>)))) ; add "operand" to list, advance recursion
```

For the second part, the general idea goes like this:

```
(define (write-to-file path string-list)
  (call-with-output-file path
    (lambda (output-port)
      (write <???> output-port)))) ; how do you want to write string-list ?
```

Of course, in the above procedure you can fiddle with the body of the `lambda` to produce the output as you expect it from the list of strings, for instance - as a list of strings, or a string in each line, or as a single line with a series of strings separated by spaces, etc. You'll invoke both procedures like this:

```
(write-to-file "/path/to/output-file"
               (check input))
```